# Cretae date picker for day only in Calender view programmatically

Tags: android, datepicker, programmatically-created

I have tried the DatePickerDialog, but there I was given options to select day, month and year.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog= new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, 2015, 11, 1);
dialog.show();

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //  Do task
    }
};
```

But I want to pop up a dialog on click of button for the selection of day only, from 1 to 31 in calender view format and **capture the day value** on Onclick. I am not able to find any solution on this one. Dialog will look something like this..

[image]

Comment: I think you should define a custom view to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code..

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth, this, year, month, day);
```